# Как отображать блок div только при скролинге?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня есть код который выводит содержимое ссылки при нажатии на кнопку.
Но как выводить содержимое ссылки при прокрутке страницы?

```
$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScBdfQmMdOt1cwpuqwg7uPYQS295zY0vnCRo',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Вместо click используйте [scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Comment: @scroll а какой порог зажожен в функцию скрол, инными словами сколько пикс нужно прокрутить что бы сработало?

Comment: Событие скролл срабатывает каждый раз когда "скроллится". Как вариант можно использовать .one() чтобы сработало только при первом скролле.
Либо в скролл доабвить функцию проверки scrollTop

Comment: @Nilsan не сработала функция

Comment: Вы точно правильно все сделали?

Comment: @Nilsan да все так как вы сказали

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).one("scroll", function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/4',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data.title);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result" style="height:2000px;"></div>
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Вот как пример, скрольните вниз и вверху появится ответ от ajax, сработает один раз при первом скролле.